# Extracting an 2D array from other array

Tags: java, arrays

This is school work related, so I'm limited not to use ArrayList or Array methods.

Let's say I've got an 2D char[][] array like this

```
ooooo
oxxoo
oxxxo
oxxoo
```

What method should I build to create a new char[][] array, if I'm given it's dimensions and starting point in the middle (dimension being always odd integer)? Starting from original array at for an example [1][3], and with size of three, the new array should be a 'cut' of it like

```
oxx
oxx
oxx
```

I'd understand if the starting point is the 0,0 of the new array, or always at the beginning of the old one, but here the middle point where to build new array around it could be anywhere.

Comment: You should use loops, with the right indices and bounds. I think the whole point of the exercise is to figure these out.

Answer (score 0):

No different than from beginning. So for starting at [1][3], instead of copying 
`newArray[i][j] = oldArray[i][j];`

use
    `newArray[i][j] = oldArray[i+1][j+3];`
Just be sure to check bounds for legal values.